# Difference between ibeacon and eddystone

Tags: android, ibeacon, beacon, eddystone

I'm new with the beacon technology and I have some doubts. What is the difference between ibeacon and eddystone format? I want develop an indoor navigation app with beacons in Android. I read some articles that ibeacon protocol is better for indoor navigation. It is true? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used on Android there is no advantage for indoor navigation apps for either format.  Both use Bluetooth LE advertisements with a different byte and identifier sequence.

The iBeacon format has advantages on iOS in that you can detect the packets quickly in the background, where as with Eddystone you cannot.  But this difference only applies to iOS.  If you are working only with Android, there is no such disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

for more understanding refer this two links just to interact with android and ios device .both can transmit and receive information like Range proximity etc.

iOS
https://github.com/AltBeacon/ios-beacon-tools

Android
https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library